# How to add or remove nodes at runtime in NS2

Tags: ns2

1. I am working with ns-2, and i would like to know whether it is possible to add or remove nodes at runtime in NS2. If it is possible kindly guide me through the steps for doing so. If this is not possible please tell me a simulator where i can do this.
2. I would also like to know whether it is possible to switch between two protocol like DSR & AODV in ns2.If it is possible please guide me through the steps for doing so.
   Thanks!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you might get more feedback if you show your research so far, and/or give more information about what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Once You create then you cannot remove nodes at run time. if you are working with wireless network instead of removal you can move your nodes outside of network range.